# SSO with signing and signature validation doesn't work

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I have succesfully configured *SSO* using *WSO2IS 4.6.0* and *spring saml* grails plugin, but when I enable signing and signature validation like this: [image]
I see errors on WSO2 console

```
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  Signature Validation Failed for the SAML Assertion : Signature is invalid.
DEBUG org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Unable to evaluate key against signature
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  Signature validation for Authentication Request failed.
```

I exported default public key (`wso2carbon`) from WSO2 keystore (`wso2carbon.jks`), and inserted certificate into `X509Certificate` section in my SP and IdP metadata.
Here is my IdP metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EntityDescriptor entityID="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
<IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>***
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                         Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"
                         ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                         Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                         Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
</IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

And SP metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="local" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
<md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:Extensions>
        <idpdisco:DiscoveryResponse xmlns:idpdisco="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Location="http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml/login/auth/alias/localhost?disco=true"/>
    </md:Extensions>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>
                    ****
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/***/saml/SingleLogout/alias/local"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost:8080/***/saml/SingleLogout/alias/local"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://localhost:8080/***/saml/logout/SingleLogout/local"/>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:8080/***/saml/SSO/alias/local" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://localhost:8080/***/saml/SSO/alias/local" index="1" isDefault="false"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

My concern is that I use wrong certificate in either SP or IdP metadata, or it should be signed somehow.

What certificate should I use for IdP and what for SP metadata, and can I check if they are valid?
How can I get it properly using public key exported from WSO2 keystore?
Thank you!

UPDATE: It works on 5.1.0 even with incorrect certificates in metadata, looks like an issue. Here is 5.1.0 Configuration:
[image]

Comment: Why are you not using IS 5.1.0 which is the most recently released version?  4.6 is a quite older version and most of the issues that were available there are now fixed in 5.1.0

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna we are going to upgrate to 5.1.0, but for now we are on 4.6.0. Actually I tried this on 5.1.0, but it worked even with incorrect certificates in metadata, looks like an issue.

Comment: It is better if you can start with IS 5.1.0. Can you attache screen shot of SP configuration in IS 5.1.0 ?

Comment: @Gayan screenshot attached

Answer (score 1):

You have to import your IDP (Server) certificate as a trust in your SP machine.. Your IDP is hosted as https so.. Import IDP trust  In SP box at your custom certificate location/JDK Cacerts (`Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts`)    and then you can try the below command to check your IDP descriptor URL is accessible from SP box  like...

```
wget "YOUR_IDP_DESCRIPTOR_URL";
```

Comment: @Taras Kohut  alos ensure you have mapped key and  certificate in application-security.xml file  properly...  E.g.    <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
   <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:keycloak.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="password"/>
    <constructor-arg>
     <map>
      <entry key="YOUR_ALIAS_NAME" value="YOUR_PASSWORD"/>
     </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="prmsaml"/>
   </bean>