# What is the purpose of signingKey and encryptionKey settings

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229219/sso-with-signing-and-signature-validation-doesnt-work), but I decided to separate it.
I have **signingKey** and **encryptionKey** settings in my grails spring saml config. What is their purpose? I read the [spring-security-saml doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-extended) and [grails saml plugin doc](http://sphoortia.github.io/grails-spring-security-saml/docs/guide/configuration.html), but it's still a little bit unclear. Could anyone explain their practical usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of them as:

`signingKey` = outbound requests

`encryptionKey` = inbound data:

i.e. the key you will use to sign outbound requests (e.g. AuthnRequest) vs. the key that your integration partners will use to encrypt assertions that are destined for you.

In the [SAML metadata standard](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf) they are allowed to be the same value or you can specify different keys for each:

> 2.4.1.1 The  element provides information about the cryptographic key(s) that an entity uses to sign data or receive encrypted keys
>
> `use [Optional]` Optional attribute specifying the purpose of the key being described. Values are drawn from the KeyTypes enumeration, and consist of the values `encryption` and `signing`